# VB.Net AES Encrypted value does not match with http://extranet.cryptomathic.com/aescalc/index

Tags: vb.net, aes

I am writing code in VB.Net to AES encrypt a string of HEX Bytes with 16 in length and expecting the same length result.

I found C# code from Microsoft website (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.aes?view=netframework-4.8) and used https://codeconverter.icsharpcode.net/ to convert this to VB.Net, ofcourse did few changes for making this to work in VB.Net

Below is the modified code for calling as well as Encryption and Decryption. I am missing something which results in a 16 (what is sent) +48 byte length encrypted value. What I need is a 16 byte HEX value encrypted using AES, ECB mode

Below is the Calling Code

```
Private Sub ProcessData()
    Dim original As String = sKi
    Dim encryptedKi() As Byte
    Dim KeyBytes() As Byte = {"&h" & Mid(sK4, 1, 2), "&h" & Mid(sK4, 3, 2), "&h" & Mid(sK4, 5, 2), "&h" & Mid(sK4, 7, 2), "&h" & Mid(sK4, 9, 2), "&h" & Mid(sK4, 11, 2), "&h" & Mid(sK4, 13, 2), "&h" & Mid(sK4, 15, 2), "&h" & Mid(sK4, 1, 2), "&h" & Mid(sK4, 3, 2), "&h" & Mid(sK4, 5, 2), "&h" & Mid(sK4, 7, 2), "&h" & Mid(sK4, 9, 2), "&h" & Mid(sK4, 11, 2), "&h" & Mid(sK4, 13, 2), "&h" & Mid(sK4, 15, 2)}
    j = 0
    Using myAes As Aes = Aes.Create()
        myAes.Key = KeyBytes
        encryptedKi = clsCryptoDES.EncryptStringToBytes_Aes(original, myAes.Key, myAes.IV)
        For x = 0 To encryptedKi.Length - 1
            sKi = sKi & Mid("0" & Hex(encryptedKi(x)), Len(Hex(encryptedKi(x))), 2)
        Next x
    End Using
End Sub
```

'Below are the codes for encryption and decryption

```
Public Shared Function EncryptStringToBytes_Aes(ByVal plainText As String, ByVal Key As Byte(), ByVal IV As Byte()) As Byte()
    If plainText Is Nothing OrElse plainText.Length <= 0 Then Throw New ArgumentNullException("plainText")
    If Key Is Nothing OrElse Key.Length <= 0 Then Throw New ArgumentNullException("Key")
    If IV Is Nothing OrElse IV.Length <= 0 Then Throw New ArgumentNullException("IV")
    Dim encrypted As Byte()

    Using aesAlg As Aes = Aes.Create()
        aesAlg.Key = Key
        aesAlg.IV = IV
        aesAlg.KeySize = 128
        aesAlg.Mode = CipherMode.ECB
        Dim encryptor As ICryptoTransform = aesAlg.CreateEncryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV)

        Using msEncrypt As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream()

            Using csEncrypt As CryptoStream = New CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write)

                Using swEncrypt As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(csEncrypt)
                    swEncrypt.Write(plainText)
                End Using

                encrypted = msEncrypt.ToArray()
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using

    Return encrypted
End Function

Public Shared Function DecryptStringFromBytes_Aes(ByVal cipherText As Byte(), ByVal Key As Byte(), ByVal IV As Byte()) As String
    If cipherText Is Nothing OrElse cipherText.Length <= 0 Then Throw New ArgumentNullException("cipherText")
    If Key Is Nothing OrElse Key.Length <= 0 Then Throw New ArgumentNullException("Key")
    If IV Is Nothing OrElse IV.Length <= 0 Then Throw New ArgumentNullException("IV")
    Dim plaintext As String = Nothing

    Using aesAlg As Aes = Aes.Create()
        aesAlg.Key = Key
        aesAlg.IV = IV
        Dim decryptor As ICryptoTransform = aesAlg.CreateDecryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV)

        Using msDecrypt As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream(cipherText)

            Using csDecrypt As CryptoStream = New CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read)

                Using srDecrypt As StreamReader = New StreamReader(csDecrypt)
                    plaintext = srDecrypt.ReadToEnd()
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using

    Return plaintext
End Function
```

Expected Output

878CB02AA535DB9BEA77FA9107F4A29B

http://extranet.cryptomathic.com/aescalc/index?key=0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF&iv=00000000000000000000000000000000&input=6E67229083422AD33A096657F0D01761&mode=ecb&action=Encrypt&output=

Actual Result (16 byte Plain string + 48 byte encrypted result)
6E67229083422AD33A096657F0D01761E03A1ED32270B4E934017D8429871CC7F78392C21477DD25BF1C633E146071063D844DC896DD1B285351FC8BE5C7CB42

Comment: Does it decrypt to the original text? That's what you'd normally care about, not the intermediate cipher block value.

Comment: The issue is that the value will be decrypted by our customer who will use method as per the Cryptomathic link that i had provided

Comment: You can display the example code from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.aes?view=netframework-4.8 in VB, rather than C#, by selecting the language from the option strip near the top of the page. No need to use the converter website then, in case the conversion is the source of the unexpected results.

Comment: Thank you, I have found the VB.Net code from Microsoft link and I just added a line to convert the received byte() to Base64String. The result is changing every time I run the program and the length is 64 characters string.

Comment: FYI the received length is 64 characters string.  <br/>  the current result is : iLbxTNLpg2UAvz1rLsnWarHteY/o97e37BYsCCqDwfQe2RBqJQbqaXdzcYS+fXmE   <br/> whereas I expect this 878CB02AA535DB9BEA77FA9107F4A29B, can anyone help me

Comment: If the result is changing on each run, that would make sense if the IV was being used - the AES.Create method initializes the IV property with a random value. But ECB doesn't use IV because it doesn't block chain, so that doesn't make sense. (FYI - this is why ECB should not be used for encrypting data, CBC is much more secure with a random IV generated for each session).  Are you sure you're using ECB and not the default CBC (despite the posted example code)?

Comment: Also - you may be calling the stream write method with the 'hexed' input in a string (can't tell from the posted code)? That could account for the output being longer than expected. And it appears that you're encrypting binary data? So using a binarywriter, rather than a streamwriter, with the input in a byte array might produce better results.  (A char array or string will be unicode, thus could be "twice as long" as the apparent data. Depends on the implicit codepage conversions that are probably occurring under the hood)

Comment: I am using ECB as per my code and the result is a 48 byte random value. I’m not sure where am I going wrong.